# Source code of netstat

Tags: networking, source, netstat

Can I view the source code of `netstat` on my Linux machine?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can. Download it.

But as you don't say what flavor of linux re you using here is couple of examples:

Debian/Ubuntu related:

```
# What package is the netstat executable in?
apt-file search /usr/bin/netstat
# Now download the source of that package
apt-get source net-tools
```

CentOS/Red Hat:

```
yumdownloader --source net-tools
```

Comment: I thought that in Linux are some standard places where I can view source code of various commands without need of downloading.

Comment: `apt-get` ends with this message `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for netstat`

Comment: Then you'll need to enable the src repos. Go to /etc/apt/sources.list and uncomment the deb-src lines.

Comment: `apt-get` with `net-tools` seems to download it, but where is it saved?

Comment: @xralf: you need to explicitly download the source code because most of the distros and users consider it as a waste of space since they trust the build process from the distro.

Comment: @xralf: it is saved in the current working directory. You'll have download several packages that include among others the original source and the distro patches

Comment: Yes, it's there, strange that on second try :-)

Answer (score 5):

`netstat` is part of the `net-tools` suite. The project home page is here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/

You can browse the `netstat` source here: http://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/ or [view the netstat.c file](http://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/netstat.c).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need this: http://www.tazenda.demon.co.uk/phil/net-tools/.
If you need more precise answer - use your local package manager to get info about package containing `netstat` utility.